# Nested Json file to csv using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am new to python and need help in converting a nested json file to csv.
File name: users.json
file path: C:/_apps/test

---

File Content:

```
{
    "count":  3,
    "next":  null,
    "previous":  null,
    "results":  [
                    {
                        "user": "@{id=1111; email=pqr@abc.com; first_name=Ann; last_name=pqr}",
                        "active":  true,
                        "marketing_optin":  null,
                        "enrolled_at":  "2018-05-08T18:22:15.125868Z",
                        "expires_at":  null,
                        "access_code":  null
                    },
                    {
                        "user":  "@{id=2222; email=xyz@abc.com; first_name=Benn; last_name=xyz}",
                        "active":  true,
                        "marketing_optin":  null,
                        "enrolled_at":  "2018-05-08T18:41:46.905016Z",
                        "expires_at":  null,
                        "access_code":  null
                    },
                    {
                        "user":  "@{id=3333; email=rst@abc.com; first_name=Cathy; last_name=rst}",
                        "active":  true,
                        "marketing_optin":  null,
                        "enrolled_at":  "2018-05-08T18:41:47.015329Z",
                        "expires_at":  null,
                        "access_code":  null
                    }
                ]
}
```

The output file format should be as shown below:

```
user_id,user_email,user_first_name,user_last_name,active,marketing_optin,enrolled_at,expires_at,access_code
```

So, far I tried with different methods and none of them gave the required result.
I was not even able to read the json file.
I tried below code :

```
with open('C:\\_apps\\users.json') as data_file:
  data = data_file.read()
  data_content = json.loads(data)
```

But is it throwing the below error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Posting the code below which currently I am trying with:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import argparse


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, user=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], user + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, user + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[user[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Converting json files into csv')
    parser.add_argument(
        "-j", "--json", dest="users.json", help="C:\_apps\training\output\", metavar="FILE", required=True)
    print(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

    with open(args.json_file, "r") as inputFile:  # open json file
        json_data = json.loads(inputFile.read())  # load json content
    final_data = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(elt) for elt in json_data['results']])

    with open(args.json_file.replace(".json", ".csv"), "w") as outputFile:  # open csv file

        # saving DataFrame to csv
        final_data.to_csv(outputFile, encoding='utf8', index=False)
```

And it throws an exception at

```
 args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are probably looking for a way to normalize your json input using pandas.

pandas has a specific method for this kind of things and it is called `json_normalize()` ([more info on the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html?highlight=json_normalize#normalization)).

```py
data = #your json here
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

After loading this into a dataframe you should be able to easily write it in .csv using pandas `to_csv()` method ([more info on the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)).

Comment: The first issue which I face is to read the json file to an object. There itself I am getting the error: ValueError: Expected object or value

Answer (score 0):

As the 'user' field is not a valid python dict, we have to parse it manually and extract all values:

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse

def extract_results(jsonfile):
    # Extract 'results' field
    res = pd.read_json('data.json')['results'].apply(pd.Series)

    # Process 'user' column
    user = res['user'].str[2:-1].str.extractall('([^=]+)=([^\;]+);?(?:\s+|$)')
    user = user.droplevel('match').pivot(columns=0, values=1).add_prefix('user_')

    # Merge data
    df = pd.concat([user, res.drop(columns='user')], axis='columns')

    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Converting json files into csv')
    parser.add_argument(
        "-j", "--json", dest="jsonfile", type=argparse.FileType('r'), metavar="FILE", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    results = extract_results(args.jsonfile)
```

```
>>> results
    user_email user_first_name user_id user_last_name  active marketing_optin                  enrolled_at expires_at access_code
0  pqr@abc.com             Ann    1111            pqr    True            None  2018-05-08T18:22:15.125868Z       None        None
1  xyz@abc.com            Benn    2222            xyz    True            None  2018-05-08T18:41:46.905016Z       None        None
2  rst@abc.com           Cathy    3333            rst    True            None  2018-05-08T18:41:47.015329Z       None        None
```

Comment: I tried this, but getting the below error while trying to read the json file: ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: Have you try the code first on your sample? On which line the exception is raised?

Comment: yes, I tried your code and it is throwing error at line :                                                     res = pd.read_json('users.json')['results'].apply(pd.Series)                                                                                           below is the error:   loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: Do `import json; json.load(open('data.json'))` raised an exception?

Comment: Yes,     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Your json file is not clean. You have to fix it. Can you share your file?

Comment: I already posted the file content in the post. I don't see any other option to attach as it is.

Comment: I updated my solution including the `argparse` part because your code didn't work for me.

Comment: error: the following arguments are required: -j/--json